# Tools to document/visualize call graph?

Tags: visualization, call-graph

having recently joined a project with a vast amount of code to get to grips with, I would like to start documenting and visualizing some of the flows through the call graph to give me a better understanding of how everything fits together. This is what I would like to see in my ideal tool:

- every node is a function/method
- nodes are connected if one function can call another
- optional square box in between detailing conditions under which call is made (or a label icon you can hover over like a tooltip)
- also icon on edge describing parameters
- hover over node and description is displayed
- optional icons for node to display pseudo code
- scenario/domain view - display subset of complete diagram for particular use-case
- slide view mode - for each frame, the currently executing function is highlighted
- plenty of options over what to display to reduce on-screen clutter

the interactive use of such a tool is key, I'm not looking for a Graphviz type solution because there would be too much clutter. The ability to form a view of a subset of the entire graph would be very handy (maybe with the unimportant clutter greyed out). Don't need automatic generation from source code, happy to enter it manually.

Almost like a mind-map.

Does that make sense? If you are not aware of such a tool, do you also think it would be useful? (Just in case I decide to go and scratch that itch one day!)

Comment: Happy to enter call graph by hand?  How on earth will you keep it up to date?

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention the environment you're using, but if it's .NET, [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) might come in handy.

Comment: Hi, the code is on a mainframe, but I would to do the visualization under Windows.

Comment: Any language specifics? A cursory glance at your profile seems to indicate you're working with Java (in one form or another). There is a Java variant/clone of NDepend called JDepend (http://www.clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html) (surprise, surprise ;), probably NDepend was based on that). I don't have more than rudimentary experience with Java, and none with JDepend, so you'll have to evaluate yourself.

Comment: I am the NDepend lead, I confirm, on first NDepend release back in 26th April 2004, the tool name was chosen based on JDepend :o)

Answer (score 2):

To develop further the answer of *Willem van Rumpt*, with the tool [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx), you can indeed obtain a [call graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx) like this one. *Disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the tool*

[image: Call graph]

For that you just need to export to the graph the result of a [CQLinq code query](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL):

[image: code query exporting]

Such a code query, can be generated actually for any method, thanks to the right-click menu illustrated below.

[image: Select methods that use me directly or indirectly]